# Dynamically create array of objects, from array of objects, sorted by an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to match and group objects, based on a property on each object, and put them in their own array that I can use to sort later for some selection criteria. The sort method isn't an option for me, because I need to sort for 4 different values of the property.

**How can I dynamically create separate arrays for the objects who have a matching property?**

For example, I can do this if I know that the form.RatingNumber will be 1, 2, 3, or 4:

```
var ratingNumOne = [],
    ratingNumTwo,
    ratingNumThree,
    ratingNumFour;

      forms.forEach(function(form) {
      if (form.RatingNumber === 1){
         ratingNumOne.push(form);
} else if (form.RatingNumber === 2){
     ratingNumTwo.push(form)
} //and so on...    
  });
```

The problem is that the form.RatingNumber property could be any number, so hard-coding 1,2,3,4 will not work.

How can I group the forms dynamically, by each RatingNumber?

Comment: What's the relation between the array and the rating number? Can you specify?

Comment: You could sort 'form' on the 'ratingnumber' then perform a split on when the 'ratingnumbers' change and push the data from the split in the arrays.

Comment: The "forms" array is an array of objects, so each form has a property of RatingNumber. These could be anything from 0-1000+.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, something like this:

```
forms.reduce((result, form) => {
  result[form.RatingNumber] = result[form.RatingNumber] || []
  result[form.RatingNumber].push(form)
}
,{})
```

the result would be object, with each of the keys is the rating number and the values is the forms with this rating number.
that would be dynamic for any count of rating number

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object and take `form.RatingNumber` as key.

If you have zero based values without gaps, you could use an array instead of an object.

```
var ratingNumOne = [],
    ratingNumTwo = [],
    ratingNumThree = [],
    ratingNumFour = [],
    ratings = { 1: ratingNumOne, 2: ratingNumTwo, 3: ratingNumThree, 4: ratingNumFour };

// usage
ratings[form.RatingNumber].push(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an object with the "RatingNumber" as property:

```
  rating = {};
    forms.forEach(function(form) {
        if( !rating[form.RatingNumber] ){
            rating[form.RatingNumber] = []
        }
        rating[form.RatingNumber].push( form )
    })
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this its a work arround:

```
forms.forEach(form => {
if (!window['ratingNumber' + form.RatingNumber]) window['ratingNumber' + form.RatingNumber] = [];
window['ratingNumber' + form.RatingNumber].push(form);
});
```

this will create the variables automaticly. In the end it will look like this:

```
ratingNumber1 = [form, form, form];
ratingNumber2 = [form, form];
ratingNumber100 = [form];
```

but to notice `ratingNumber3` (for example) could also be undefined.

Just to have it said, your solution makes no sense but this version works at least.

Comment: Which part am I not making sense? I'll update my question, I might not be asking this as clearly as I can. The reason I need to sort through these by RatingNumber is because a later part of the code needs to restrict the selection of forms to only 4 different rating periods.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what numbers you are getting with `RatingNumber`, just use it as index. The result will be an object with the `RatingNumber` as indexes and an array of object that have that `RatingNumber` as value.

```js
//example input
var forms = [{RatingNumber:5 }, {RatingNumber:6}, {RatingNumber:78}, {RatingNumber:6}];
var results = {};
$.each(forms, function(i, form){
    if(!results[form.RatingNumber])
        results[form.RatingNumber]=[];
    results[form.RatingNumber].push(form);   
});
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HIH

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Example input data
let forms = [{RatingNumber: 1}, {RatingNumber: 4}, {RatingNumber: 2}, {RatingNumber: 1}],
    result = [];

forms.forEach(form => {
    result[form.RatingNumber]
        ? result[form.RatingNumber].push(form)
        : result[form.RatingNumber] = [form];
});

// Now `result` have all information. Next can do something else..

let getResult = index => {
    let res = result[index] || [];
    // Write your code here. For example VVVVV
    console.log(`Rating ${index}: ${res.length} count`)
    console.log(res)
}

getResult(1)
getResult(2)
getResult(3)
getResult(4)
```